# How to use activity in cocos2d-android?

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-android

i'm currently working on cocos2d-android project where the interaction between the sprite is done using 'scenes' havent used xml files, so now to do some other tasks i'm using xml layout files on onTouch of a button. 
below is the code to replace the scene on onTouch of the button, since scene not been used what logic should i use here? i searched a lot, could not find the solution. please help me.

```
public void callbackGameLayer(Object sender) {
    //Global.playSoundEffect(R.raw.button);
    CCScene scene = CCScene.node();
    scene.addChild(new GameLayer(), -1);
    CCDirector.sharedDirector().replaceScene(scene);

}
```

this is the activity to which the flow has to go

```
public class IntermediateMain extends Activity {

protected CCGLSurfaceView mGlSurfaceView;
private static int MAX_GAME_TIME_SECONDS = 300;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    // get full screen setup and keep screen bright and on when the window
    // is visible
    getWindow().setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);


    mGlSurfaceView = new CCGLSurfaceView(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);  

    final Button newGame = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_game_btn);
    final TextView numSecondsTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.num_seconds_text_view);
    final TextView numSacksTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.num_sacks_text_view);
    OnSeekBarChangeListener changeListener = new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            int currentGameTimeInSeconds = (progress * MAX_GAME_TIME_SECONDS) / 100;
            numSecondsTextView.setText(Integer
                    .toString(currentGameTimeInSeconds));
            numSacksTextView.setText(Integer.toString(IntermediateGameLayer
                    .numSacksInGame(currentGameTimeInSeconds)));
            newGame.setEnabled(currentGameTimeInSeconds > 0);
        }
    };
```

Comment: when you tried to run this demo , What Happened .?

Comment: i got error on this line scene.addChild(new GameLayer(), -1);, this is due to absense of "extends CCLayer" in the class @AM

Comment: hmm .. I tried also to call from Scene to Activity but it'll not allow to do this thing .. Only we can work on the CCLayer .. If something i'll get to solve this thing . I'll inform you about this

Answer (score 0):

I think you have gone to the wrong direction because i have the same intention as you before,but after a series of research,I have found out that:the cocos2d-x API for Android  is only a wrapper for working properly on android device.The major development language is still C++ for portability,[Here is a **Space Game** example support my point](http://www.raywenderlich.com/33752/cocos2d-x-tutorial-for-ios-and-android-space-game).

Answer (score 0):

To switch to another activity in Android, you need to send the call from cocos2d-x (c++) to the current android activity using JNI code. And then start a new activity there. The cocos2d-x game will pause when you switch to another activity.